# How to use unicode in regex for extracting particular information?

Tags: python-re

I intend on extracting information from a test string before applying it on the main data set. Here I want to extract values like '1234/ब भाग ','345/ब','54' from the string:
test = "1234/ब भाग abbcdjhc 345/ब - 54 मध्दे आहे"

```
My code: 
test = "1234/ब भाग abbcdjhc 345/ब - 54 मध्दे आहे"
import re
re.findall(r"\d+/[\u0900-\u097F]* | \d+",test)

my output:
['1234/ब ', ' 345', ' 54']

expected output:
['1234/ब ', ' 345/ब', ' 54']
```